# data validation field in excel

Tags: java

I want to know how to create a data validation field(list) in excel sheet through java code...Is there any method in jxl package that can create a data validation field.?

Comment: And what kind of data validation are you wanting to do? Do you want the java to do the validation or for it to leave some kind of validation in the excel?

Comment: data validation filed is like a combo box in excel sheet(data->validation->list)...
i can create a excel sheet and insert values into it through jexcelapi...but i dunno how to create a combo box in it...

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Java Doc for [WritableCellFeatures](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6/docs/jxl/write/WritableCellFeatures.html). There are a few method in there that deal with Validation.

I think jxl.write.WritableCellFeatures.setDataValidationList(java.util.Collection c) is what you are looking for. If not, this should point you in the right direction.